# Need help identifying bmx bike possibly redline?

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

Need help identifying frame has handlebars with marking redline no other markings where found grips say mongoose

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

<sub>Images from https://flic.kr/p/2oVZxxd</sub>

Comment: Aside - you appear to be missing a back-left axle nut on the wheel, and brakes.  Don't ride it without a full methodical check over.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Is there a specific reason to identify it?  For example, identification isn't necessary for finding replacement parts.

Comment: It looks like the bike has no brakes.

Answer (score 1):

The key indicators for manufacturer on this frame are the rear dropouts the curved one piece seat stay and the brake bridge.

[image]
The dropout is a sheet metal part with pinched tubing welded.

[image]

The slotted brake bridge allows for a variety of brake arm lengths to be used and both of these are typical of a department store bike. Murry or Huffy.

Similar to, and maybe exactly like, this [1985 Murray Street Style](https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/murray/124551).
[image]

Your bike has been retrofitted with nicer pedals, handlebar stem, seatpost, handlebars, chainring and grips.

Answer (score -1):

The redline bars are definitely  worth $$$ they are forklifts bars very sought after in the bmx world for the redline RL20. Pedals look to be mosh maybe wellgo seat post looks like possibly SR laprade or SR sakae ALWAYS people looking for them but the bars are money the stem looks to be Dk but if u pull it and it will be stamped on the tube